# Python help on if((var[0] > 6) && (var[0] < 19)) : needed

Tags: python, if-statement, python-2.7

I'm fairly new on Python2.7 and got most of my job done, but the
term

```
if((var > 6) && (var < 19)) :
```

will give a syntax error (of course) but I cannot understand how to
do this in Python

What I want is to have a true (to get in the body of if) if the content 
of var ist between 6 and 19 (this will be for a clock 6am-7pm)
could somebody please point to the working solution?

Comment: In python `&&`  is written as `and` , next time use google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In python, [boolean AND is spelled `and`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

```
if var > 6 and var < 19:
```

In this case, you can use [comparison operator chaining](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

```
if 6 < var < 19:
```

and forgo the boolean test altogether. This is essentially the same as `(6 < var) and (var < 19)` except the expression in the middle is evaluated only once.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I'm lookg for. Even after reading the text in the python manual only your example made it clear. Think I have to look for a book about comparison.